# Detect when an object touches the edge of the screen

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipod-touch

If I have an object of arbitrary height and width that moves around the screen, what's an elegant way of detecting when it touches the edge of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your coordinate system. Assuming a coordinate system with (0|0) at the lower left corner you have those cases:

- Touches left edge if `object.origin.x <= 0`
- Touches right edge if `object.origin.x + object.size.width >= screenSize.width`
- Touches bottom edge if `object.origin.y <= 0`
- Touches top edge if `object.origin.y + object.size.height >= screenSize.height`

This also works for irregular shaped objects if you use the bounding rectangle for the object.

Comment: If you're using the origin then doesn't that allow the object to go out of the screen?